# Sharing $_SESSION variables across subdomains using PHP

Tags: php, session, subdomain

I am trying to share the contents of the session variable across two subdomains but for some reason it is not working.

The **sessionid** is exactly the same on both subdomains but the variables aren't available.

I can achieve this with Cookies and this is working but would rather use the values in the session.

Here is how I'm setting the domain for the session:

Thanks,
Scott

**UPDATE**
Sorry should have said, I am already using the following:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],"."),100));

if(session_id ==''){session_start();}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for this function: [`session_set_cookie_params()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).
Say you have two domains:

1. site1.example.com
2. site2.example.com

In order to share your session data across both domains, call the following functiontion before `session_start()`:

`session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');`

(Edit: indeed I forgot a dot in the example code)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - could you expand on your comment please, I am not sure if you are saying that what I trying to do won't work or the code that has been provided by Rodin is incorrect.

Comment: @scott refer to http://php.net/setcookie manual for the proper domain setting. note the number of dots

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - This is the output from the session_get_cookie_params function:

    array(5) { ["lifetime"]=>  int(0) ["path"]=>  string(1) "/" ["domain"]=>  string(23) ".domain.com" ["secure"]=>  bool(false) ["httponly"]=>  bool(false) }

Comment: @scott well with dot it should work. check HTTP headers. to see what is going wrong

Comment: Is there something specific I should be looking in the HTTP headers?

Answer (score -1):

> The sessionid is exactly the same on
>   both subdomains (..)

Are you sure that the *value* (not the name) of sessionid is the same?

I needed similar thing 2 years ago, but I needed it to work on completely different virtual hosts (e.g., example.com and something.else.net), so I wrote a small script that ensures that user gets the same `session_id` on different virtual hosts. Source code is available at http://www.misc.lv/_downloads_file.php?id=18, but there's small bug on line 58 - arguments of strpos() should be swapped (I'm too lazy to fix it and upload fixed script).

Basic requirements/steps are:

1. all pages should be on the same server, as they need a common "storage" for session variables;
2. there must be one "main" host; there's no limit on a number of "additional" hosts;
3. if currently opened page is on the "main host" (and it is not a request of session_id), nothing "extraordinary" has to be done;
4. if page is not on the "main host" and there is an active session, nothing "extraordinary" has to be done, as session_id probably has already been shared;
5. if page is not on the "main host" and there is no active session, request a session_id from the "main host".

Comment: Yes both sessionid values are exactly the same.
Both subdomains are on the same server.